# Change background color of a div temporarily on click and then set to a different color

Tags: javascript

Another noobie question. Trying to create a smartphone app using html, css, js and phonegap build. When the user taps a button or image I'd like to change the div background color from white to yellow, then play a short sound clip and then set the background color to say a pale yellow.

I will have dozens of these Divs and all have a class assigned. Some will have a class .formal, others .informal and others .spanish. So far I can get it to play the sound only. I've tried adapting other solutions I've seen but the background color won't change. I think I need to identify which instance of the class was clicked, then change only that bg color then play the sound and finally change the bg color to light yellow. I have removed some code for clarity below.

Thanks for any assistance you can provide me.

Here's the html for a sample div

```
<div class="formal">
  <a href="#" onclick="playAudio('/android_asset/www/test.mp3');">Play ay caramba</a>
</div>
```

And here's the "playAudio" js

```
function playAudio(src) {
  // Change bg color for the div to yellow here
  if (my_media == null) {
    // Create Media object from src
    my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
  } // else play current audio
  // Play audio
  my_media.play();
  // change background color to light yellow here  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If can use jquery to do that

you will have something like that

```
     function playAudio(src) {
 // Change bg color for the div to yellow here
 $("formal").css('background-color','yellow');
 if (my_media == null) {
        // Create Media object from src
        my_media = new Media(src, onSuccess, onError);
    } // else play current audio
    // Play audio
    my_media.play();
  // change background color to light yellow here
  $("formal").css('background-color','blue');  
    }
```

you can put a hex color to get the color that you want

Comment: Thanks, I see you're changing the CSS for the formal class but I think that will change all of the entries in the .formal class right? I just need to change the color of the one item that was clicked and there will be dozens of items with the .formal class. Also, the playAudio function needs to figure out which class was clicked, there are 3 classes that it could be - .formal, .informal and .spanish. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I tried using toggleClass and had no success. Here's what the js looks like now